# Matrix Multiplication returning wrong value

Tags: c#, matlab, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I am calculating values by using weights and bias from `MATLAB` trained ANN. trying to code a sigmoid simulation equation, but for some reason C# calculations vary too much than that of MATLAB. i.e. error is too high. I tried to check each step of the equation and found out the specific part that is creating the problem (Emphasized part), but I don't know how to solve this issue, if someone could help, would be a huge favour.

1+(purelin(net.LW{2}×(tansig(net.IW{1}×(1-(abs(2×([inputs]-1)))))+net.b{1}))+net.b{2}))/2

```
//Normalization of Data
        public double Normalization(double x, double xMAx, double xMin)
        {
                double xNorm = 0.0;
                xNorm = (x - xMin) / (xMAx - xMin);
            if (xNorm < 0)
                xNorm = 0;

            if (xNorm > 1)
                xNorm = 1;
        xNorm = Math.Round(xNorm, 4);
        return xNorm;
    }

        // Equation to calculate ANN based Output Values
        public double MetrixCalc(double[] Pn, double[,] W1, double[] W2, double[] b1, double b2, double maxValue, double minValue)
        {

            double FinalValue = 0;

            double[] PnCalc1 = new double[Pn.Length];
            double[] PnCalc2 = new double[W1.Length / Pn.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < Pn.Length; i++)
            {
                PnCalc1[i] = 1 - Math.Abs(2 * (Pn[i] - 1));
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < (W1.Length / Pn.Length); i++)
        {
            double PnCalc = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Pn.Length; j++)
            {
                PnCalc = PnCalc + (W1[i, j] * PnCalc1[j]);
            }
            PnCalc2[i] = PnCalc;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < PnCalc2.Length; i++)
        {
            //PnCalc2[i] = Math.Tanh(PnCalc2[i] + b1[i]);
            PnCalc2[i] = PnCalc2[i] + b1[i];
            PnCalc2[i] = 2.0 / (1 + Math.Exp(-2 * (PnCalc2[i]))) - 1;
            PnCalc2[i] = Math.Round(PnCalc2[i], 4);
        }

        double FinalCalc = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < PnCalc2.Length; i++)
        {
            *FinalCalc = FinalCalc + (W2[i] * (PnCalc2[i]));*
            //FinalValue = FinalCalc;
        }

        FinalValue = FinalCalc + b2;
        FinalValue = 1 + FinalValue;
        FinalValue = (1 + FinalValue) / 2.0;
        FinalValue = (FinalValue * (maxValue - minValue)) + minValue;
        FinalValue = Math.Round(FinalValue, 4);
        FinalValue = Math.Abs(FinalValue);

        return FinalValue;
        }
```

Comment: c# and MATLAB both use 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point for their `double` data type, so there shouldn't be a difference in precision. You have probably made a coding error or there is some difference in logic. Can't tell you what, since I have nothing to compare your code to.

Comment: Thanks. It is very tiresome though. I cannot spot the error.

Comment: Been there. Take a break. If that doesn't work, consider doing a complete rewrite (no peeking). If you can, change the structure of your c# program to match the structure of your MATLAB program, and use the exact same variable names as much as possible, so that a 1:1 comparison is easier. You can always change it back to c#-style code once you have a known good algorithm.

Comment: Could you please post the baseline MATLAB code? Or at least the name of the function(s) that you're trying to replicate in C#?

Comment: Actually ANN is developed through nftool in MATLAB so, I am just using the generated weights and bias to implement this equation. This is the simulation equation, I'm trying to code.
1+(purelin(net.LW{2}×(tansig(net.IW{1}×(1-(abs(2×([inputs]-1)))))+net.b{1}))+net.b{2}))/2

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. 
Problem was with the weights matrix copied from MATLAB. debugging mode saved my life. :)